# ASP.NET 4 Parser Error

Tags: asp.net, html, asp.net-4.0

I received a asp.net 2 to upgrade to .net 4. While most of it went well I'm stuck on a line that can't find a solution for it.

I get a `Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.`

at this line

```
<li><a class="tooltip viewPolicyLink" rel="<%#Eval("key")%>"
              title="<%#Eval("value")%>"
              href="<%#ResolveUrl("~/Views/Pages/ViewPolicy.aspx")%>"
              runat="server"><%#Eval("key")%></a></li>
```

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have messed with `"`
try :

```
   <li><a class='tooltip viewPolicyLink' rel='<%#Eval("key")%>'
                  title='<%#Eval("value")%>'
                  href='<%#ResolveUrl("~/Views/Pages/ViewPolicy.aspx")%>'
                  runat="server"><%#Eval("key")%></a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Double quotes are nested in rel, title, href attributes.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use single quotes when setting tag values that contain the `Eval()` expression. The reason being is the double quotes that `Eval` takes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using single quotes for the attributes containing server-side commands:

```
<li><a class="tooltip viewPolicyLink" rel='<%#Eval("key")%>'
              title='<%#Eval("value")%>'
              href='<%#ResolveUrl("~/Views/Pages/ViewPolicy.aspx")%>'
              runat="server"><%#Eval("key")%></a></li>
```